# Python optparse, default values, and explicit options

Tags: python, optparse

Take the following rather standard code:

```
from optparse import OptionParser                         
opts = OptionParser()
opts.add_option('-f', action="store_true")
opts.add_option("-x", dest="x", type="int", default=1)
options, args = opts.parse_args()
```

Assume that `-x` and `-f` are mutually exclusive: when `-x` and `-f` are both explicitly present, an error should be reported.

How do I detect if `-x` is present explicitly? Even if it is not, `options` list the default value.

One way would be to avoid setting the default value which I rather won't do because `--help` prints default values nicely.

Another way would be checking `sys.argv` for instances of `-x` which is a bit awkward, too, if there's more than one name for `-x` (that is, a --long-name) and there's more than one pair of mutually exclusive options.

It there an elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html). There's a section for [mutually exclusive groups](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion):

> **argparse.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)**
>
> Create a mutually exclusive group. argparse will make sure that only one of the arguments in the mutually exclusive group was present
>   on the command line:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
>>> group.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
>>> group.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo'])
Namespace(bar=True, foo=True)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--bar'])
Namespace(bar=False, foo=False)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo | --bar]
PROG: error: argument --bar: not allowed with argument --foo
```

[optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) is deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You can accomplish this with `optparse` using a callback. Building from your code:

```
from optparse import OptionParser

def set_x(option, opt, value, parser):
    parser.values.x = value
    parser.values.x_set_explicitly = True

opts = OptionParser()
opts.add_option('-f', action="store_true")
opts.add_option("-x", dest="x", type="int", default=1, action='callback',
                callback=set_x)
options, args = opts.parse_args()
opts.values.ensure_value('x_set_explicitly', False)

if options.x_set_explicitly and options.f:
    opts.error('options -x and -f are mutually exclusive')
```

Let's call this script `op.py` for now. If I do `python op.py -x 1 -f`, the response is:

> Usage: op.py [options]
>
> op.py: error: options -x and -f are mutually exclusive